# Fixing hot plate and the heat sink, which thermoelectric module would produce more power?

Tags: power-electronics, semiconductors, thermal, heatsink, peltier

Thermoelectric coolers (TECs) are typically used to generate temperature difference. Thermoelectric generators (TEGs), however, are used for power generation. While TECs are much cheaper than TEGs, they are not optimized for power generation.

Assuming we are going to use TECs for power generation:
Fixing hot plate and the heat sink, which of the following thermoelectric module can produce more power?
TEC1-12702, TEC1-12706, or TEC1-12710.

Link to datasheets:

http://www.thermonamic.com/TEC1-12702-English.pdf

http://www.thermonamic.com/TEC1-12706-English.PDF

http://www.thermonamic.com/tec1-12710-english.pdf

Note that as TECs are used as coolers, not generators, directly using specs from datasheets may not give accurate results (e.g. multiplying *V* and *I*, doesn't give the correct generated power range).

As I'm new to this area, would you please elaborate on your answer?

Comment: Those are thermoelectric coolers. They do not produce power. We do not evaluate spec sheets. No question about electrical engineering design or theory has been asked. Voting to close the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about electrical engineering design or theory.

Comment: Correct! TECs are not typically used to generate electricity, they are to make temperature differences. However, they are cheaper than the TEGs. My question is if I'm gonna use TECs for power generation, which one of them produces more power under the same circumstances. This is related to theory. I couldn't find any good equations/producedure on Internet to explain it.

Comment: Their datasheets should help answer that question.

Comment: Their datasheets are for their own purpose of cooling. If we use that data, we come up with the wrong conclusion :). Am I right? That's why this is a tricky question. I can edit the content of the question to show this.

Comment: Someone may answer if you revise your question to make it more clear, and link the spec sheets for the devices. I am not sure how a request for analysis of an unconventional use of a device will be viewed.

Comment: Sure, I'll revise the question and add the datasheets link. Thanks.

Comment: I retracted my close vote, but someone else voted to close since my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This TEC is 58% efficient with 170W in and 50’C difference.  Efficiency goes down with higher temperature difference needed to reverse the process and may in fact be not equivalent.

I suggest if you input a 50’C temperature difference and load the TEC with some MPPT regulator to match the source impedance to the load, you might compute the thermal resistance and heat required to raise this temperature difference on each side, you might be lucky to get 50% efficiency.

From the C.O.P. Graph vs V the maximum is 0.6 at 8V with DT=40’C. Whatever output current that is for this temp. Rise of input heat and DT=40’C gives you your current and the slope or incremental W/V=I results in your ESR =V/I which is your MPPT load current and resistance. @ 8V.

I’ve never used these before, but that’s my SWAG. (Super Wild xxx Guess)